# WebKitWebProcess / Gdk-Error when trying to run a Tauri app in a container via x11 connection

Tags: docker, x11, tauri

I'm trying to display a basic Tauri app GUI running in a Docker container but connected to the host's X11 server through a unix socket. But I get the following warning and error when running `npm run tauri dev`:

```
(WebKitWebProcess:6009): Gdk-ERROR **: 00:17:37.147: The program 'WebKitWebProcess' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 258 error_code 2 request_code 152 (GLX) minor_code 34)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

I get opened a GUI window on the host but it's blank (but should contain some text / HTML markup).

As I am able to get Firefox and Gedit running from within the container but not the gnome-terminal, I think it's some permissions issue or there is some missing package to get the Webkit based GUI window connecting to my host's X server.
`$DISPLAY` and `/tmp/.X11-unix` are set properly. On the host I set `xhost +`

The container is running as `node` user. Cargo is installed in `/home/node/.cargo/bin`.  `/home/node` is owned by `root:node` with `775` permissions on folders and `664` on files (`+x` on executable scripts).

I'm just getting started with Rust and Tauri and also not a big expert on X server and Docker networking.

Any ideas how to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Qemu + Virt-Manager instead of docker. For the starters I've used an Ubuntu template as the clipboard sharing works out of the box with my host running on Ubuntu as well. Sound sharing and video playback works out of the box, too. And if I should get in the situation where I would need a separate VM for each app, then I would use my minimalist Arch template to spin up the VM's - the size should be pretty close to that of a docker container.

Edit:
LXC/LXD and Podman might be even better alternatives, I have been told.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `ipc = "host"` in your docker command or docker-compose.yml file. This fixed the issue for me, although I had other error codes.